# .Net class helper method

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance, extension-methods

Is there a way to add a method to a class, but allow it still be inherited by the base class?

I have the following

```
public class ListWithRandomize<T> : List<T> {
   public void Randomize() { // Randomize function}

}
```

I'm going to have a bunch of List objects that will need to be randomized.  Is it possible to have a List object that I can just "Make" into a ListWithRandomize object?  I suppose I could just make the randomize function static and have it take a List<> as a parameter, but I'd like to have it as a method of the class.. if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) is the only way you can add a method to a class when you don't have access to the source.

Keep in mind that an extension method is not an actual member of a type -- it just looks like that in your source code. It cannot access private or internal variables -- at least, not without reflection, but you probably don't want to do that.

> *I suppose I could just make the randomize function static and have it take a List<> as a parameter, but I'd like to have it as a method of the class.. if possible.*

In that case, an extension method is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want an extension method, e.g.

```
public static void Randomize(this List<T> list)
{
    // ... 
}
```

This is a static method that will appear to be an instance method on `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [C# 3.0 Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) would do what you are trying to accomplish here.

```
public static class MyListExtension {
  public static void Randomize(this List<T> list){...}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about an [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) method?

```
public static void Randomize<T>(This IList<T> list)
{
    //randomize
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension Methods. You can add the Randomize method to List. This code was written here so it may not complile. It should give you a start though.

```
public static class Extenstions
{
   public static List<T> Randomize<T>(this List<T> list)
   {
      // randomize into new list here
   }
}
```